# HIVE query takes very long time to fetch 20 gb records

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, hiveql

Hi I have a hive table on HBASE that has 200gb of records .
I am running simple hive query to fetch 20 gb records .
But this takes around 4 hours of time .
I can not create partition on HIVE table cause it is integrated on HBASE.

Please suggest any idea to improve performance

This is my HIVE query

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/hadoop/user/m6034690/FSDI/FundamentalAnalytic/FundamentalAnalytic_2014.txt'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
select * from hbase_table_FundamentalAnalytic  where FilePartition='ThirdPartyPrivate' and FilePartitionDate='2014';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can, then I think Apache Phoenix will speed things up.

https://phoenix.apache.org/faq.html

Very simple and intuitive to use and super fast.

Comment: Oh Thanks .So i have an existing HBase table with data and i can convert it like HIVE and phoenix also .?

Comment: Install Phoenix and its sqlline.py client (very easy to do). Then create a view over your existing HBase table. Now run queries like "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ...." Phoenix is fast and it acts as a front end for HBase. You interact with Phoenix and it manages HBase automatically. You can even create a secondary index and the performance gain will be huge. Look here http://www.akashnegi.com/copy-of-ny-taxi-data

Comment: Yes true but Phoenix is not installed on my cluster as it is not budded withj CDH 5 .Not released for production

Comment: The query looks OK by itself. See if you can run a full scan of table with your filter conditions (where FilePartition='....) without involving Hive and compare that time to the 4hrs. If the time is significantly less than it is the Hive end which is slowing things up. If that also takes 4 hrs then I guess it is the usual problem of Hive-over-HBase being slow.